# Mathematica does not plot my expression

Tags: plotting, functions

Mathematica does not plot the expression.

```
1/2 Sqrt[-(77/12) (72/77 + Cos[x/2]) - 2 Sqrt[5929/576 (72/77 + Cos[x/2])^2 - 
  77/4 (17/28 + Cos[x/2] + (43 Cos[x])/308)]]
```

Why not?

Comment: Because there are imaginary parts in your expression. Try `Plot[ Abs[1/2 Sqrt[-(77/12) (72/77 + Cos[x/2]) - 
   2 Sqrt[5929/576 (72/77 + Cos[x/2])^2 - 
      77/4 (17/28 + Cos[x/2] + (43 Cos[x])/308)]]],{x,0,4 Pi}]`

Comment: But this is Absolute Value.I need real part but I could not use Re function in wolfram.

Comment: If I plot your function  `f = 1/2 Sqrt[-(77/12) (72/77 + Cos[x/2]) -2 Sqrt[5929/576 (72/77 + Cos[x/2])^2 -77/4 (17/28 + Cos[x/2] + (43 Cos[x])/308)]]`  in the complex plane `ParametricPlot[{Re[f], Im[f]}, {x, -10, 10}]` I get a strictly imaginary output, so the realpart `Re[f]==0` seems to vanish !?

Comment: Really,I dont know.But assume that Real part is zero.Why  does mathematica not plot?

Comment: @user54260 : MMA plots a zero line, in the example I gave to you in my last comment , you see a straight line along the imaginary axes...

Answer (score 0):

In such cases: take a look at your root. It has the form `Sqrt[a[x]]-2b[x]]` where `b` is again a root, then looking at the terms under the root(s):

```
a[x_] := -(77/12) (72/77 + Cos[x/2]);
```

and

```
    b[x_] := 5929/576 (72/77 + Cos[x/2])^2 - 
   77/4 (17/28 + Cos[x/2] + (43 Cos[x])/308);
```

then one can investigate separately:

```
Plot[{a[x], b[x]}, {x, -10, 10}]
```

delivers:

[image]

So we have only a small region (between 5 and 8) where `b[x]`is positive, but the overall value under the root is not:

```
Plot[a[x] - 2 Sqrt[b[x]], {x, 5, 8}, AxesOrigin -> {0, 0}]
```

so: No plot in the real plane.

[image]

You can additionally do:

```
reg = ParametricRegion[{Re[f[x]], Im[f[x]]}, {{x, -10, 10}}]
```

and then `Region @ reg`delivers:

[image]